# URL amigável dinâmica .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Atualmente possuo a seguinte regra no .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^fale-conosco/?$ view/fale_conosco.php [NC,L]`

E gostaria que fosse possível informar uma URL amigável após o fale-conosco/.

Exemplo:

`fale-conosco/ajuda`

Para isso estou usando uma regex porém não está funcionando:

`/^fale-conosco\/*([a-zA-Z0-9])*/g`

Já tentei várias expressões regulares porém até agora nada deu certo.

Quando testei no [regexr](https://regexr.com) deu erro quando adicionei `localhost` na frente do restante da URL, como ignorar o que estiver na frente do `fale-conosco/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

Ignorar o antes e passar o depois por parametro: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/fale-conosco/(.*)?$ view/fale_conosco.php?parametro=$2 [NC,L]`.

Esqueci de explicar: o primeiro `(.*)` pega qualquer coisa antes de `/fale-conosco` (que fica armazenado em `$1`), o segundo `(.*)` pega tudo depois de `/fale-conosco`, que fica em `$2`.

---

Você pode por `RewriteRule ^fale-conosco/.*?$ view/fale_conosco.php [NC,L]`. Tudo após `fale-conosco/` vai ser ignorado.

Testei neste site: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Eu preciso que o que esteja antes do `fale-conosco/` seja ignorado e o que estiver depois dele eu vou passar por parâmetro.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, funcionou?

Comment: Demorei para responder porque acabei esquecendo, mas funcionou sim...